# C# how to separate a string list and add each value to its own string property

Tags: c#, database, list, mapping

I have a mapping file to map values to a model to save to my database.  In my database table I have 6 fields (Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4, Key5, Key6).
My model looks like this:

```
public string Key1 { get; set; }
public string Key2 { get; set; }
public string Key3 { get; set; }
public string Key4 { get; set; }
public string Key5 { get; set; }
public string Key6 { get; set; }
```

I get the values in my mapping file like this:

```
.ForMember(dto => dto.Keywords, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<string> { src.Key1, src.Key2, src.Key3, src.Key4, src.Key5, src.Key6 }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))));
```

However, I now want to do it the other way around, so that the values can be changed and sent back to the database.  I would like to do it in just one line, like how I get the list in the first place.
Currently I'm having to do an `ElementAtOrDefault()` on the list to get each value to store in each field if its not null.

My current code:

```
entity.Key1 = dto.Keywords.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != null ? dto.Keywords[0] : null;
entity.Key2 = dto.Keywords.ElementAtOrDefault(1) != null ? dto.Keywords[1] : null;
entity.Key3 = dto.Keywords.ElementAtOrDefault(2) != null ? dto.Keywords[2] : null;
entity.Key4 = dto.Keywords.ElementAtOrDefault(3) != null ? dto.Keywords[3] : null;
entity.Key5 = dto.Keywords.ElementAtOrDefault(4) != null ? dto.Keywords[4] : null;
entity.Key6 = dto.Keywords.ElementAtOrDefault(5) != null ? dto.Keywords[5] : null;
```

Is there an easier way?

Comment: I assume that if `Key4` is empty, then `Key5` and `Key6` must also be empty, right? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to map shorter lists back to `KeyNNN`s.

Comment: If there isn't a simple way, don't worry about it.  I just wanted to know if there was.  What I currently have works, I just wanted to simplify it if possible.  I'll put the code I currently have above

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: Any reason for having `Key1`, `Key2`, ... ? Are they used in any query or as integrity constraints? Otherwise, why not use a single column `Keys` that is delimited in an appropriate manner? Or saved in e.g. Json format

Comment: Its an old database that was created by some "not so experienced" people.  Unfortunately database migration has stopped us from changing this, so we have to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method for `IList<T>` to help you:

```
public static T ValueOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> source, int index)
{
    return source.Count > index ? source[index] : default(T);
}
```

And use it as below:

```
entity.Key1 = dto.Keywords.ValueOrDefault(0);
```

I can't see many other ways to simplify that aren't going to detract from the readability.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of functions taking DTOs and making assignments, and "fold" the loop to a single line:

```
private static Func<MyDto,string,string>[] Setters = new Func<MyDto,string,string>[] {
    (dto, s) => dto.Key1=s
,   (dto, s) => dto.Key2=s
,   (dto, s) => dto.Key3=s
,   (dto, s) => dto.Key4=s
,   (dto, s) => dto.Key5=s
,   (dto, s) => dto.Key6=s
};
```

With this declaration in place you can do this:

```
dto.Keywords.Zip(Setters, (str, setter) => setter(entity, str)).ToList();
```

The call of `ToList()` forces enumeration of the call to `Zip`, which executes the assignments to members of the `entity` as it enumerates the list. The call stops when the end of the list is reached.

This assumes that the strings in `Keywords` are non-null and non-empty.

Note that if the list is shorter than 6, the remaining `KeyXYZ`s would retain the values that you have previously assigned to them. If you would like to force the assignment to `null` for the remaining values, use `Concat` method, like this:

```
dto.Keywords
    // This line adds nulls for missing items
    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(null, Math.Max(Setters.Length-dto.Keywords.Length, 0)))
    .Zip(Setters, (str, setter) => setter(entity, str))
    .ToList();
```

The call of `Math.Max(..., 0)` adds protection for situations when the list has more items than there are `Key`s in the DTO.

Comment: Cool, cheers.  That does work apart from what you mentioned at the end, but I can soon find a way around that.